# Es posible cambiar el mensaje de true y false cuando imprimo por consola a si y no?

Tags: java

Este es el metodo.

Quisiera poder imprimir si o no en vez de true o false, se que es boolean, solo quisiera saber si es posible o no con una cadena de carecteres auxiliar o con condicional

```
public boolean estaDentro(Rectangulo r) {
return  (centro.getX()-r.getVerticeII().getX())  >=radio && 
                ((r.getVerticeSD().getX())-centro.getX())>=radio &&
                (centro.getY()-r.getVerticeII().getY() ) >=radio &&
                (r.getVerticeSD().getY()-centro.getY())  >=radio
                ;      
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el operador condicional ternario cuando llamas al método para imprimirlo en la consola

```
System.out.println(estaDentro(r) ? "Si" : "No");
```

El uso seria esta `(condición) ? si : si no`

Otro ejemplo seria querer imprimir si una cadena es igual a otra sin que devuelva true o false y sin agregar `if` y `else`

```
String string1 = "Uno";
String string2 = "Uno";

System.out.println(string1.equals(string2) ? "Es igual" : "No es igual");
```

Al igual que en el método podrías pasarlo a un String y utilizarlo también

```
public String estaDentro(Rectangulo r) {
    return  ((centro.getX() - r.getVerticeII().getX()) >= radio && 
            ((r.getVerticeSD().getX()) - centro.getX()) >= radio &&
            (centro.getY() - r.getVerticeII().getY()) >= radio &&
            (r.getVerticeSD().getY() - centro.getY()) >= radio) ? "Si" : "No";      
}
```

O directamente agregar un `if-else` pero intuyo que no quieres hacer eso porque la pregunta no tendría sentido.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score -1):

No entiendo bien el contexto de tu pregunta, tu programa según el resultado imprime por consola True o False? de ser así, para lograr lo que tu quieres, tienes que crear un condicional nada mas e imprimir "si", "no". el boolean son palabras reservadas y no se pueden modificar, pues la computadora no entenderia.

Comment: si como podria hacerlo trate pero me da error.